# Animate a falling cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a tapestry on a wall, and I want it to fall. Preferably, I'd like one of the top corners to come loose first, so it starts to fall towards that side; then the other top corner would come loose, and then the whole thing would end up in a reasonably realistic pile on the floor.

I've tried messing around with something like the curtain tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVGnvVij9Oc . But A) I can't keep the cloth from going through the wall my tapestry is hanging on, and B) even if it would stay out of the wall, I can't figure out how to animate the falling part.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not looking at the tutorial at the moment, but off the top of my head it sounds like a super standard cloth simulation.

Comment: Is there some trick to keeping a cloth from intersecting what it touches?

Comment: yes. Select the object I.e. the wall, go to Properties -> Physics, and enable Collision.

Comment: doh. well that was dumb of me. Next dumb question, I hope: how do you pin the corners up? I tried a Fixed empty, but that doesn't seem to work for cloth (tooltip says "rigid bodies")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another option. It's using the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier and good
to simulate a poorly glued wallpaper that is coming off the wall.

[image: animation]

The cloth simulation has a *Pin* group. The weights of this group are modified by the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier which is controlled by a hidden cube. (Don't forget to hide it for render.)

[image: screenshot]

In the cloth settings, you need to set the *Collision > Distance* to a small value like (`0.005`). Place the control cube very close to the wallpaper and give it enough geometry. In the example, the default cube with 5 subdivision levels is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ***Vertex Weight Mix*** modifier.

Don't subdivide your wallpaper mesh too much if you don't want it to look too flexible. You can create 2 groups: The *Pin* group (the whole paper except the 2 top corners) and a group with no vertex that you'll call *NoPin*. Give your paper a *Vertex Weight Mix* modifier, then *Cloth*, then *Subidivision Surface*. In the *Physics panel > Cloth > Shape* choose the pin group. In the *Vertex Weight Mix* modifier, select Vertex *Group A* (Pin) *and B* (NoPin). Choose *Vertex Set > VGroup A or B, Mix Mode > Replace*. Keyframe the *Global Influence* value the way you want in order to mix from A to B:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Thanks!

Comment: you can even create 2 objects and replace the first one when it has finished its simulation

Comment: Master of wallpaper +1

Comment: @Chris, it was not my fault, the glu was too bad

Comment: @moonboots : and who bought the glue? 