# How to pick up a cloth simulation

Tags: animation, physics

I've recently watched Disney's Encanto, and I am in love with the clothing design. I've been doing some experiments in blender, and something that I just can not figure out is how to pick up a cloth half way through a simulation. Essentially I want to use a Hook modifier in conjunction with a cloth simulation, in which the hook only takes effect part way through. I have set up this example scene in which a cloth falls onto a ball. I have an empty in the scene which I would like to pick up the cloth and drag it off the ball, from a particular vertex.

[image: Example Scene]

I would imagine that this would involve a Hook modifier, but I'm still stumped.

Comment: did you use your vertex as PIN in cloth simulation? If yes, please provide blend file

Comment: I didn't use the vertex as a pin, because I don't want it to be pinned all of the time, just sometimes. Is there any way I can do this using the pinning functionality?

Comment: nope. you have to use pinning. You can adjust the pinning by using vertex weight edit modifier. Set the weight of that pin to 0 as long as it shouldn't pin.

Comment: Maybe take a look at Blunder's answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/243170/animate-a-falling-cloth/243181?noredirect=1#comment413856_243181 ... or you could move another collision object?

Comment: Thank you Chris that really helped

Comment: you are welcome